# MSSQL Server Pages

Tags: sql-server, data-pages

Looking online I have found a lot of information describing how pages work, what they are used for, and how they tie into the architecture of MSSQL Server. I understand they are a part of the mdf file created to store the data itself, however what I'd like to know is how are pages stored on disk. Is each page (or extent) itself a file on disk, or is it just data contained a giant mdf file?

Reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-files-and-filegroups?view=sql-server-2017) it seems like that latter is true, but it is not completely clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pages in SQL Server are basically logical concept designed to store data and access it.

Quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) and similar [StackOverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864899/how-is-data-stored-in-sql-server).

> Storage space allocated to a database is divided into sequentially
>   numbered pages, each 8 KB in size. A page is the basic unit of I/O for
>   SQL Server operations. A page is marked with a 96-byte header which
>   stores metadata about the page including the page number, page type,
>   free space on the page and the ID of the object that owns it. Page
>   type defines the data contained in the page: data stored in the
>   database, index, allocation map which holds information about how
>   pages are allocated to tables and indexes, change map which holds
>   information about the changes made to other pages since last backup or
>   logging, or contain large data types such as image or text. While page
>   is the basic unit of an I/O operation, space is actually managed in
>   terms of an extent which consists of 8 pages. A database object can
>   either span all 8 pages in an extent ("uniform extent") or share an
>   extent with up to 7 more objects ("mixed extent"). A row in a database
>   table cannot span more than one page, so is limited to 8 KB in size.
>   However, if the data exceeds 8 KB and the row contains varchar or
>   varbinary data, the data in those columns are moved to a new page (or
>   possibly a sequence of pages, called an allocation unit) and replaced
>   with a pointer to the data.[21]

Comment: Thanks, I guess it is getting very low level to ask how SQL Server allocates and references the 8kb pages on disk?

Comment: @Rumham, I think [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/pages-and-extents-architecture-guide) explains space allocation well.

Comment: Nothing is *very low*, a question is question. I may not be able to describe how actually it stores because that is beyond scope but wiki would give you some idea that would give fair understanding.